# How do grab attributes data in this protected object

Tags: php, apache, object, protected

since i am not good at js or jquery at all, i decided to do a captcha entirely using php and classes. So i end up passed the variables a few times but for me that is better than having to deal with js or jquery.

But on the last stop here before i do the output of the input field i am having some trouble getting the attributes data from the object that i made lol.

I always remembered the basic rule (i know its korny lol) that objects you shoot with arrows, arrays you dont, so i know with objects you use ->

$setidfield is the object

so i have tried all of these

```
$inputname = $setidfield->name;
$inputname = $setidfield->attributes->name;
$inputname = $setidfield->attributes:protected->name;
```

all of which do not work :(

here is the object.

```
    CAPTCHA_CLASS_Idfield Object
 (
 [jsObjectName] => uid_captcha_input_omusuh1g
 [validators:protected] => Array
    (
    )

 [filters:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[required:protected] => 
[value:protected] => 
[errors:protected] => Array
    (
    )

[label:protected] => 
[description:protected] => 
[attributes:protected] => Array
    (
        [name] => qid
        [id] => input_omusuh1g
        [value] => 3
        [type] => text
        [maxlength] => 5
    )

)
```

Comment: I just noticed the last part is an array not an object so i need to use [' '] right  however it says i cant use it as an array when i try that

Comment: You're trying to access a protected member variable, which is not allowed. Look in the documentation of the captcha library you are using to find the appropriate getter method. It'll be something like, `$setidfield->getName()`. Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: I am not using a library im creating it myself i just use a class to set the object values, ok ill check the link

Comment: Thanks for the reply...  all i am trying to do is just post the question db id so i can pull it afterwords and compare the question and answer. I already have the custom captcha part done, im just working on the reply end of it.  So i have a better way for this part so i dont have to use the object at all other than just for the jsObjectName which is dynamic. I have all the other data that i need already with regards to type and value.  So i will just forgo the object other than for the name and just post the input as a string rather than let the system functions do it.